Not able to access plugins in sub modules even after applying them to current project
Root build.gradle file
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android) apply true
    alias(libs.plugins.android.library) apply true
}

module2's build.gradle file
android {
    namespace = "com.example.module2"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 24

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles("consumer-rules.pro")
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
}

showing error
Unresolved reference: android
From what i have learned that if u apply a plugin in root project u apply it to whole project and don't need to apply it again.

Unfortunately, you learned wrong. You need to apply each plugin in each subproject you want it.
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
}

Plugins are nothing more than a program that runs at the start of your build to make pre-set configurations to a given Project object. "Applying" a plugin starts that program (performed by default in the plugins block). Therefore each plugin needs to be applied to each Project object where it is needed.
Note the line
alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false

is not applying the plugin anyhow (apply false being the giveaway). This line adds the plugin code to the classpath of the build (shared across the subprojects of the build) to avoid the clashes which could happen if the same code is loaded twice.
